# Does all browsers needs atleast one style information to start rendering?

Tags: css

Do all browsers start rendering as soon as they have at least one embedded `<style>` tag or at least one external CSS file downloaded or do they wait until all of the external CSS files linked in the page are downloaded?

Answer (score 2):

All explicit references to external scripts or stylesheets will block all subsequent page rendering until the resource is downloaded and executed.

This article "[How browsers work](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#The_order_of_processing_scripts_and_style_sheets)" goes into more detail and one of the references is the official [CSS 2.1 processing model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/intro.html#processing-model). This is composed from six steps where particularly

> 1. ...
> 2. ...
> 3. Retrieve all style sheets associated with the document that are specified for the target media type.
> 4. ...
> 5. ...
> 6. Transfer the formatting structure to the target medium

Comment: @madth3: I'm not sure where this is specified.  http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#The_order_of_processing_scripts_and_style_sheets  Note that this behavior avoids FOUCs.

Comment: Well, that page appears to have some research behind and that CSS 2.1 reference is good. I'd add to the answer.

Comment: Added what I though were some relevant bits from the source you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

For html the rendering engine will display contents on the screen as soon as possible. It will not wait until all HTML is parsed before starting to build and layout the render tree.
Style sheets on the other hand have a different model. Conceptually it seems that since style sheets don't change the DOM tree, there is no reason to wait for them and stop the document parsing. There is an issue, though, of scripts asking for style information during the document parsing stage. If the style is not loaded and parsed yet, the script will get wrong answers and apparently this caused lots of problems. It seems to be an edge case but is quite common.

**[Source](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#Render_tree_construction)**

Browsers run many threads concurrently for resource downloads. Stylesheets, html, scripts they all run in a different thread, and for html the browser doesn't wait for all content it start creating `DOM tree` and side by side the `render tree` is also being constructed as soon as the style data is available. **So in short browsers creates a map tree in memory for style rules but it doesn't paint it unless all the css are downloaded.**

you might have seen in firebug that all css are downloaded asynchronously and noticed DOM has changed many times it's because of scripts changing css and render frame is recreated.

FYI : Firefox blocks all scripts when there is a style sheet that is still being loaded and parsed. Webkit blocks scripts only when they try to access for certain style properties that may be effected by unloaded style sheets.

Comment: I have seen lots firebug water fall diagrams, where Firefox browser starts to render as soon as first style sheet is downloaded. But, i could not conclude is it really after the first style sheet download or is it that HTML download is complete and started to build DOM tree. Basically when browser generates the start render even, for example HTML page is very big and it has reference to external CSS files distributed across the page from top to bottom. I have a similar question with regard to HTML page, do we start parsing as soon as first chunk is received or wait till we get all the bytes?

Comment: yes we do parse as soon as we get first chunk of style but we do not apply it to DOM unless each n every link style is available. answer updated